# Copy data schema to clipboard in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

Through Amazon Aurora, I've got connection to hundreds of unknown tables with different schema. I need to figure out which one of them has got a field (or column name) that contains a particular text as substring, say `freq`. Loading these tables one by one into Tableau Worksheet and then manually checking their schema is proving extremely cumbersome task and error-prone.

Is there a way to get the schema of all these tables into some textual form like `Tablename : Colm1, Colm2, ..., ColmN`?

or, is it possible to right click on a table in Tableau and get `Copy Schema to Clipboard` option?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use Tableau for this. Try this from your favorite query tool:

```
SELECT table_name, column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE column_name like '%freq%'
```

Comment: Unless you connect Tableau to information_schema.columns

Comment: Very true. Thanks @AlexBlakemore!